# How to run docker container with file updates for slateDocs?

Tags: docker

I'm following this steps to build and run slatedocs with Docker: https://github.com/slatedocs/slate/wiki/Using-Slate-in-Docker

I edit the files stop the container and then run the provided command:

```
docker run --rm --name slate -p 4567:4567 -v $(pwd)/source:/srv/slate/source slatedocs/slate serve
```

To serve again, but it does not reflect the updates for the file.

How can I build and serve with the changes I made?

Comment: i think this is happening due to persistence. remove the old files before building again.